# Difference between a PC and a Mac?

Tags: windows, linux, macos, mac, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install Mac OS X on customized hardware?](https://superuser.com/questions/24624/is-it-possible-to-install-mac-os-x-on-customized-hardware)

Well I think the title is the main question here and aside from that:

- What is it that does not allow the MacOS to be installed on a normal PC ?
- How do I install the MacOS on a PC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to rumor, there's hardly any hardware difference anymore. Macs run Intel CPUs, nVidia/AMD GPUs and I believe Seagate HDDs. Pretty stock stuff.

There is a difference at the OS level and the BIOS (or equivalent) needs to be compatible with that. Things like [EFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface) and [GUID partition tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) are the most notable low-level differences.

> What is it that does not allow the MacOS to be installed on a normal PC ?

Depending on your PC, potentially nothing. The hardware may not be compatible, OS X is intended for a smaller range (since Apple has more control over what it goes on than other OSes). You may be able to find third-party drivers for common hardware, though.